# For what you have stood up for

Tags: to-for

Work your ass off for what you have stood up!

or

Work your ass off for what you have stood up for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to go the angle of totally avoiding trailing prepositions but sounding stilted and unworkable, perhaps:

> Work your ass off for that up for which you have stood.

But that's horrible.

You should see the following on "hypercorrection": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercorrection

The most frequent joke example of this I've heard is "This is the type of English up with which I will not put", frequently attributed to Churchill.  See http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/001715.html

Your first sentence fails at the meaning (unless "stood up" means "initiated" in the systems sense).  Your second works fine for the meaning you're presumably going for, but it might be shunned by absolutists on the anti-trailing-preposition front.  Presumably, even they'd be OK with it in spoken English.

Answer (score 0):

'Stood for' is more prominent and meaningful than 'stoop up for', which doesn't necessarily mean 'stood for'.  'Stood up for' can be used to point/refer a hypocritical stand.  E-g. He 'stood up for' honesty in public life but he just 'stood up for' but did not 'stand for' the same.